# Emacs buffer creation/switching function

Tags: emacs

I would like to make function that creates a buffer named 'console', if it does not exist and runs a few commands.  If the buffer already exists I want it to only switch to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, obviously replacing `(insert "something\n")` with the commands you want to run:

```
(defun jump-to-console ()
  "go to console buffer if it exists, otherwise create"
  (interactive)
  (let ((buffer-name "console"))
    (if (get-buffer buffer-name)
        (pop-to-buffer buffer-name)
      (pop-to-buffer (get-buffer-create buffer-name))
      (insert "something\n"))))
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up wanting to run a shell instead in the else case, but that was easy to modify from your example.

Answer (score 4):

`get-buffer-create` ("Return the buffer specified by BUFFER-OR-NAME, creating a new one if needed.") will handle creating the buffer if one doesn't exist. Then use `switch-to-buffer` ("Make BUFFER-OR-NAME current and display it in selected window.") to switch to the buffer.

So something like this will do the trick:

```
(switch-to-buffer (get-buffer-create "console"))
```